# Getting an 'invalid return statement' and I am not sure why

Tags: javascript

I am working on coding a [Conway's Game of Life grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life).

I am new to JavaScript and I am trying to add a method to the board object that will return one `cell`'s location on the board.  But I am getting an error telling me it's an `invalid return statement`. Can you please explain what I am doing wrong?

```
         Board.prototype = {
            addCell: function(cell) {
                this.cells[getCellRepresentation(cell.x, cell.y)] = cell;
            }
            getCellAt: function(x,y) {
                return this.cells[getCellRepresentation(x,y)]
            }

        }
```

Comment: Two missing semicolons :)

Comment: @gdahl—nope, one missing comma.

Comment: That's true, and the reason why I gave the answer a +1. But the code example is also missing two semicolons, at least that's what my Netbeans told me, so as you see, my comment is not meant as an answer, as the question already was answered at the time of my comment, but merely meant as a ... comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I see is that you are missing a comma:

```
Board.prototype = {
        addCell: function(cell) {
            this.cells[getCellRepresentation(cell.x, cell.y)] = cell;
        },  // <---- put a comma here 
        getCellAt: function(x,y) {
            return this.cells[getCellRepresentation(x,y)]
        }

    }
```

The reason you need a comma is that the 2 functions are part of an initialization statement, and addCell and getCellAt are both members of the Board.prototype, and are initialized with anonymous function expressions which are members of an expression list. Consider JSON syntax.

```
var obj = {
 name: "bob",
 age: 21,
 party: function() { ... }
}
```

If the functions were normal named functions, you might see:

```
function addCell(cell) {

}

function getCellAt(x,y) {

}
```

No comma needed, because these are not assignment statements, they are individual function definitions.

Comment: You mean *individual function declarations*. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing comma.

```
Board.prototype = {
            addCell: function(cell) {
                this.cells[getCellRepresentation(cell.x, cell.y)] = cell;
            },
            getCellAt: function(x,y) {
                return this.cells[getCellRepresentation(x,y)]
            }

}
```